# Angularjs mutlilingual support using protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor, multilingual

I have been working in Angularjs application and we have already written protractor framework to test. Application need multi language support now, whereas our testscripts are in English. Can anyone suggest me how to add multilingual support for other language in existing framework
Note: we will need the English testscripts for english locale anyways.

Comment: `Can anyone suggest me how to add multilingual support for other language in existing framework` please explain these. Right now it's pretty vague.